# On AWS RDS Postgres, what could cause disk latency to go up while iOPs / throughput go down?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm investigating an approximately 3 hour period of increased query latency on a production Postgres RDS instance (m4.xlarge, 400 GiB of gp2 storage).

The driver seems to be a spike in both read and write disk latencies: I see them going from a baseline of ~0.0005 up to a peak of 0.0136 write latency / 0.0081 read latency.

I also see an increase in disk queue depth from a baseline of around 2, to a peak of 14.

When there's a spike in disk latencies, I generally expect to see an increase in data being written to disk.  But read iOPS, write iOPS, read throughput, and write throughput all went *down* (by approximately 50%) during the time when latency was elevated.

I also have server-side metrics on the total query volume I'm sending (measured in both queries per second and amount of data written: this is a write-heavy workload), and those metrics were flat during this time period.

I'm at a loss for what to investigate next.  What are possible reasons that disk latency could increase while iOPs go down?

Comment: did you find solution to the above problem?

Comment: @xiarnousx nope -- I hit a dead end investigating it, and then the issue hasn't occurred again since, so I don't have more data to work with